# Building footprints of the city of Guayaquil, Ecuador

Tags: shapefile, data, footprint, ecuador

Does anyone have/know where I can find a shapefile/dataset of the building footprints of the city of Guayaquil in Ecuador?

this type of information is so hard to get here in Ecuador. I went through all of the government database pages but there is none containing the information i am looking for.

Comment: What does OSM have (I'm guessing not much if your government databases don't but you never know)?

Comment: OSM has some https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=17/-2.19451/-79.88408 but no shapefile you will have to convert the http://download.geofabrik.de/south-america.html [.osm.pbf] (54 MB)

Answer (score 2):

Geofabrik has shapefiles you can download of OpenStreetMap data. It looks like building outlines in Guayaquil are pretty sparse, but it could get you started.

Shapefiles are available at http://download.geofabrik.de/south-america/ecuador.html
(Edit: Actually shapefiles aren't available for Ecuador strangely as mentioned in Mapperz comment. You will have to convert the pbf file)

[image]

Comment: Thank you Matthew! and yes, data in Ecuador is very hard to find. I think I am going directly to the institution in charge of city planning!

Comment: Did this answer work, or are you still looking for other potential sources for the building footprints?